# How can I access form validation attributes using a variable form name in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm generating forms in angularjs and my form has a variable name. How can I access the validation attributes in my template?

```
<form name="{{ form.name }}" novalidate>
```

If form.name is "foo", how can I access foo.$isvalid?

Comment: Have you tried `$scope[$scope.form.name].$valid` (assuming form.name is defined on the current scope).

Comment: Doesn't work, scope[form.name] is not defined when using a dynamic form name

Answer (score 0):

if your form name attribute has value 'foo', then in your template file you can access in following way:

```
foo.$valid
```

If you want to access this in your controller js file, you can do like this:

```
$scope.foo.$valid
```

Consider following code template:

In your HTML file::

```
<form name="form.name"></form>
```

In you controller js file::

```
$scope.form = {};
$scope.form.name = "foo";

$timeout(function(){
    console.log($scope.foo.$valid)
}, 1);
```

As you can see, I have consoled on timeout. If you try to fetch form before angular js compiles it, it will give you undefined. So make sure that your html file compiles before  you use form variable.

Comment: Maybe my name attribute is foo, it can also be something else, I want to access $valid from a variable form name